# Graph API does not showing all public Posts based on keywords

Tags: facebook-graph-api, public

I tried searching all public posts using "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=keyword&type=post" as mentioned in the documentation. But the JSON result is missing some posts which are public. For example i posted or shared something on my wall and i tried searching d post having specific keyword using the above api but it did not show my post. I tried finding the reason for this problem but i could'nt get it anywhere. So friends if u know the reason or solution of this problem then please do answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i've noticed this as well. a friend tried posting on his wall publicly and we could both see his results. interestingly, when i tried on the desktop i got nothing - even when switching IPs and users. however, when i posted via mobile to my feed it got picked up.